# locate and plot the minimum on a simple plot

Tags: matlab

I am new to MATLAB.  I am looking for a 'correct' implementation of a simple plot.  I have defined an anonymous function and I want to place a point at the minimum of the function.  The following code does this; but I think I am missing a more appropriate way of handling this.

```
f = @(t) t.^(8/3)-16*t.^(2/3);
fminbnd(f,0,5)
f(2)
fplot(f,[0 5],'Linewidth',2,'Color','g');
hold on
fplot(f,[2 2],'--or');
hold off
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```
f = @(t) t.^(8/3)-16*t.^(2/3);
x1=0; 
x2=5;

[x fval]=fminbnd(f,x1,x2);

fplot(f,[x1 x2],'Linewidth',2,'Color','g');     hold on
plot(x,fval,'--or');     hold off
```

by the way, you can also write the last line as:

```
 plot(x,f(x),'--or');
```